# How to set Default font-family

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to set default font family as 'Open Sans', sans-serif; for the whole project but nothing works. Am using Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Do it through CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Use Google Fonts `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: your suggestion works but still I face issue with font style.

Comment: If you want use styles, you should use another Google Fonts link `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` When you chose any font at http://www.google.com/fonts, you also should chose which styles you want, because more styles you want more time a user will wait until font is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add font file with .otf extension in \resources\css folder and replace all default font family to 'Open Sans', sans-serif in app.css file it will work.